# Access Vector in class with "class[i]" like class would be the vector

Tags: c++, class, vector

Is it possible to implement a function to access a private data vector `foo` in a class via `class[i][j]`? This should call the inner function of the vector `foo[i][j]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple solution is to implement `operator[]` so it "peels off" only the first dimension:

```
#include <cstdlib>

class MyClass
{
    std::vector<std::vector<int> > foo;

public:

    // grant write access
    std::vector<int>& operator[](size_t index)
    {
        return foo[index];
    }

    // grant read access
    const std::vector<int>& operator[](size_t index) const
    {
        return foo[index];
    }
};
```

You need the [two overloads](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/const-correctness.html#faq-18.12) because of [const correctness](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/const-correctness.html). (If you only want to grant read access, not write access, you don't need the non-const version, of course.)

Comment: I tried it, but I only get: matrix.cpp:29: error: ‘std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >& operator[](size_t)’ must be a nonstatic member function
matrix.cpp:33: error: non-member function ‘const std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >& operator[](size_t)’ cannot have cv-qualifier
matrix.cpp:33: error: ‘const std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >& operator[](size_t)’ must be a nonstatic member function

Comment: @multiholle: Fred's code is correct - you must have integrated it wrongly.  If you can't work out where your mistake is, either post more of your new code or copy-paste Fred's and work backwards to add your own functionality, checking periodically that you haven't broken anything and saving if all's good....

Answer (score 2):

You can overload `operator[]` to do this.  You might want to look at [this faq](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/operator-overloading.html#faq-13.10) for advice for using `operator()` instead.